# How can I get an array of all the messages from a text channel in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have the channel object, and I've tried

```
mess = channel.history(limit=200)
```

but `mess` is a `HistoryIterator` object and does not contain any messages in its `mess.messages` object (size = 0). There are messages in the channel, so it shouldn't say the size is 0.

I've also tried:

```
mess = client.logs_from(channel, limit=200)
```

but PyCharm tells me that `client` has no `logs_from` function.

Is there an easy way to get all of the messages from a text channel in an array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HistoryIterator` implements the [`AsyncIterator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator) interface.  You can use the [`AsyncIterator.flatten`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator.flatten) method to consume the contents of the Iterator into a list:

```
messages = await channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
```