# How can I get a list of all the messages in a channel and then pick a random message from that list to send as a message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I tried looking on StackOverflow for the answer to this question before and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349020/how-can-i-get-an-array-of-all-the-messages-from-a-text-channel-in-discord-py). I tried it out on Python 3.7 on discord.py rewrite 1.5.0. It should give me a random message from the channel I sent it in, and send it as a message.

So if there was a message among the many messages in the channel like:

> Bring me pain, sir.

It would send that message, but the message chosen to be sent would be randomized each time the command would be run.

Here's my code: (the channel is anonymized for safety reasons)

```
channel = client.get_channel(123456789101112131)
messages = await channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(messages)}")
```

Instead of a random message, it gives me a bunch of junk information relating to the guild/channel/author that sent the message. Which, while helpful, isn't what I'm going for.

If it helps, here's the gubbins (anonymized, however):

```
<Message id=42365698915833262 channel=<TextChannel id=123456789101112131 name='general' position=1 nsfw=False news=False category_id=None> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=481541758625098605 name='me' discriminator='4444' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=111222333444555666 name='GUILDNAME' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=4>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

(sorry, it won't show correctly if I don't make it code)

I have no idea why it's doing this. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm an amateur programmer, so I might be missing something completely obvious. I'm using a client.command() for the code, in case you are wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance at the docs for discord.py, [the `history()` method you're using](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.TextChannel.history) looks like it returns a list of [Messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#message). The [docs for *that* type](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Message) show that it has a [`content` property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Message.content), which sounds like what you want:

> **`content`**
>
> The actual contents of the message.

Your code is causing the whole Message object to be converted to a string, which is why you're seeing various parts of the internal representation (`category_id`, `discriminator`, etc.). Try this instead:

```py
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(messages).content}")
```