# Save every message in a channel to a txt file discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a word chaining bot on discord, and I want it to save all the messages in the channel so I can check for duplicates, is this possible?

Comment: If you want to iterate through the message history of a text channel you can simply use the example provided in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history): `messages = [message.content async for message in channel.history(limit=None)]`

Comment: I think you may want to switch to using a database though. It may become very slow and hard to check for duplicates as your data set grows if you use a text file.

Comment: Yes, through the history, but channels can easily accumulate thousands (and millions, if your channel has been up for a long time with many active members) which is really painful to fetch in the api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an array of all the messages from a text channel in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349020/how-can-i-get-an-array-of-all-the-messages-from-a-text-channel-in-discord-py)

Answer (score -2):

Of course this is possible. And it is extremely easy to do.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

log = open("log.txt", "a")

def add_message(msg):
    log.write(msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    add_message(message) # You can check the channel with message.channel.id

client.run('your token here')
```

This should work

Edit: If your concern is to check every message against every new message, as other said, switch to a database.

MySql is very easy to setup (compared to PostgreSQL) and connect to Python, and you can check for duplicates very easily.