# Skip reply to a discord message if said messages was caused by a previous one

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.guild.id in svrs:
          if message.author.id == (int(bot1)) and f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content:
            await send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{my_user_id2}> im here", 1.91)
```

Any user can ask bot1 if im online (by saying "***check***"), bot1 in turn will send a message like the one in the code above (...***f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content***) which my bot (bot2) is listening for.

I need bot2 to skip those on demand checks and only answer (***...send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{my_user_id2}> im here", 1.91)*** ) when bot1 sends the message (...***f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content***) on its own and not when another player makes it manually check.

The code above will respond 100% of the time bot1 pings me, even when a user invokes the "***check***" request.

Sorry, if I'm not expressing myself properly. This is my first python/coding project.

Thanks!

Comment: My instinct when looking at this problem is that you need to keep track of the previous message in the channel. Assuming you can't modify bot1 to indicate that the check is manual not automatic, the only way to work out if the check is manual is to look at the channel and see if it was started by someone. I would try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349698/11072533), using a limit of 2 to look at the message before the bot ping and see if was a trigger command. There might be a better way to go about this but I can't think of anything else. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Cmd858, thanks for the reply! I cannot modify Bot1 nor be online to check if a manual trigger has been made. The good thing is that bot1 responds instantly to any user's "check" message so I only need to red the previous message, at worst 2.

I wonder if there is a way to stop bot 2 from running when a users says "check" but unfortunately the program keeps running with everything I try.

Comment: If looking at message history isn't viable, you could make your bot react to the check command sent by the user as well as bot1, but have it set a global in your program to not respond to the next message from bot1. I can give some code for what this could look like if you want, although it shouldn't be too tricky I hope.

Comment: @Cmd858, checking the message history for the channel should be possible as they are not private (only thing to note is that Bot1 is accessible from multiple non-private channels in the guild but does reply to the "check" request in the same channel the user manually triggers it).

Happy to test checking History or your code suggestion. I'm literally just starting my python journey so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: If you would like, I might be able to try this myself and give an answer if I come up with anything. It would probably take a while though, since discord bots are kinda complicated.

Comment: Yes please!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect but I'll try to put it into the context of your bot and hopefully it'll work as you would like.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id in svrs:
        if message.author.id == (int(bot1)) and f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content:
            message_iter = message.channel.history(limit=2)
            messages = [msg async for msg in message_iter]
            if '!checkstatus' not in messages[1]:  # check message before bot ping for command
                # was not triggered by user so send response
                await send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{my_user_id2}> im here", 1.91)
```

Essentially it just creates a 2 item list of messages in the channel and checks the last message, which would be the check command done by the user (!checkstatus in this example). If this message isn't there, then the check was automatic and you can reply. Leave a comment is you have any questions!

Comment: I receive this error

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'messages' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Now get the error  in my next reply when I play with the code like you see in my next reply.

BTW, why did you add a **!** in front of check? Is it needed or just a typo?

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'Message' is not iterable     <br/>


`@client.event  <br/> async def on_message(message): message_iter = message.channel.history(limit=2)  messages = [msg async for msg in message_iter] if message.author.id == (int(bot1)) and f"<@{my_user_id}>" in message.content: if 'check' not in messages[1]:  # check message before bot ping for command # was not triggered by user so send response await send_delayed_msg(message.channel, f"<@{my_user_id2}> im here", 1.91) `@Cmd858

Comment: Well that’s strange, I don’t see where the `messages` variable could be used before it’s assigned, or how it could possibly end up not being a list? Maybe try printing out `messages` variable to see what it’s set to? Also the ! Isn’t needed, I just often use it ask a prefix to indicate that the message is a bot command, so you just need to put whatever format your command uses in its place.